# Azure FTP to live webpage

Tags: azure, ftp

I am not a programmer, I just want to learn Azure to host some personal webpages and the documentation is a little lax. I think some terminology regarding Azure has changed in the past few months so it makes it a bit harder trying to reference prior info.

Finally figured out how to FTP to Azure from Excel(create webpage). I can see and I can view the Excel htm from the FTP folder, but can not figure how to deploy it to the actual webpage which would be this. [link](http://cartwheel.azurewebsites.net/)

I have tried "set up deployment from source control" and chose "external repository", for the URL I gave it the FTP URL, but I do not know what the "branch to deploy" and the repository type (Git or Mercurial) are for. I have tried a few variations and continue to get a deployment failed message.

I read another thread on this forum regarding needing a storage account, which I tried to create using data services/storage/quick create. It asks for a URL and in small print underneath has .*.core.windows.net - and I don't know where to access that. Another attempt at setting up a storage account wants me to ship a hardrive, provide tracking number etc.

So can anyone give me a brief synopsis of what my next steps should be to actually deploy the webpage from the FTP area? Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is your "FTP area?" How are you currently getting to your "FTP area?"

Answer (score 2):

> So can anyone give me a brief synopsis of what my next steps should be to actually deploy the webpage from the FTP area?

When you FTP into an Azure Web App, you will encounter something like the following directory structure.

```
data
LogFiles
site
  wwwroot
```

You will want to put your website files into the `site/wwwroot` directory. For instance, if your site consists of an `index.html` and `other.html` page and an `image.png` file, you will want to end with the following structure.

```
data
LogFiles
site
  wwwroot
    index.html
    other.html
    image.png
```

Then you can access your index page at `myapp.azurewebsites.net`, your other page at `myapp.azurewebsites.net/other.html`, and your image at `myapp.azurewebsites.net/image.png`.

As for FTP clients, I recommend [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for reliability and [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) for ease of use.